# How to 'fall-back' to get increasingly coarser places if nothing interesting nearby

Tags: google-places-api

I am getting started with the Google Places API for Java/Android and JavaScript and have something running.

I would like to be able to implement a "fall-back" approach where I return results to the user sorted by distance, but if nothing interesting (place of business, airport, shopping mall, etc.) is found within a certain radius, then I would go to a coarser granularity and return street intersection, neighborhood, or city in that order. What would be best way to do this, preferably in one query?

Also, I noticed that I can specify "rankby=distance", but I cannot provide a radius, which is very inconvenient. Is there any workaround to this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of to sort by distance within a set radius, would be to manually process the returned results to see if their location falls within your specified radius. If you believe that this would be a useful feature, I would also recommend submitting a 'Places API - Feature Request' [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

A possible solution to your "fall-back" approach would be, if the a [Places API Search Request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchRequests) returns `"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"` or if no results returned fall within your desired radius, you could perform a [Geocoding API Reverse Geocoding Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) using the latitude and longitude from your Places API Search Request to find the closest address.

Comment: About the 'fall-back': So the Geocoding API seems to be completely separate from the Places API. I thought that the Places API could return street, city, state, etc. I guess I will have to make two calls, one to Places and another to Geocoding.